# QT program crashes when trying to use any function from a library

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making the assumption that it's giving me this error since it can't find the DLL. It's a well-used SDK, so I'd assume the functions would work just fine. Anyway, I included the .lib in the .pro file...

```
LIBS += -L"C:\Users\Michael\Documents\ASITest\libs" \
        ASICamera2.lib
```

I also have the correct header inclusion, but when I try using any function from the DLL, I'll get...

```
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\...\debug\****.exe crashed
```

I have tried putting the DLL in the debug folder, I've tried putting it in the root folder of the project and the folder with the .lib file. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Have you run it in a debugger to see exactly where and why it crashes?

Comment: `I'm making the assumption` don't! You are a programmer, not a fortune teller. Use debugger

Comment: I can't use the debugger. That's a whole other problem that I'm currently working on.

Comment: When loading a DLL, if any of it's dependencies are missing the load will fail. Check dependencies with DependencyWalker. If the DLL loads ok, but you are crashing when using methods from the DLL, then you had better show some code.

Comment: @dgsomerton Thank you. That's a good tool to know about. I tried it, and it listed a lot of missing dependencies, but the root ones being all Windows DLLs (setupapi.dll, kernal32.dll, user32.dll, advapi32.dll). I've used this DLL is a test program using C++ without including any of those in the build folder. I did include three other DLLs in that project (not listed by Dependency Walker). I tried those in this project, but no luck.

Comment: research MSDN about DLL search paths.

Comment: So I got the debugger working. The only error that pops up is "The CDB process terminated". I went through the logs, and it loads my application's DLL, and all of the DLLs I listed above (other than setupapi.dll, which is in my system32 folder).